# Understanding of TYPO3 folder structure for own files/directories (file list, FTP)

Tags: site-structure, typo3

sadly someone in my family decided to be a casual TYPO3 user.
I want to help him, but I don't get their directory structure and want to keep my work clean in a TYPO3 way. So here are some questions:

1. What comes directly into `/fileadmin`?
2. There is `/Resources`. Is it OK to store design related images like my sweet face, family photos, logos, icons, videos in this resource folder?
3. If not, where should for example videos be stored in?
4. Should all own folders be capitalized like `Resources`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an question how you want to make it, there is nothing you must to have.

I recommend to have your template files outside of `/fileadmin` I use often `/template` for this.

As next step you should create folders for an structure you understand.
Many customers try to place the files like the navigation structure, so they find the content belongs to them.

You can also create folders like `Pictures`, `Videos`, `PDF`and so on...

you dont need the captial letters. In TYPO3 they are use often camelCase, so it ends as example to `picturesOfWedding` or simplay `pictures/wedding/john`...

Answer (score 4):

1. **fileadmin** contains files that can be uploaded, managed and used in the TYPO3 backend, such as images, PDF, videos etc. This can be named differently or even split up into several storages, but *fileadmin* is the default. So the files in fileadmin are files that can be changed by the editor in the TYPO3 backend. You can name the subdirectories any way you want. See [File Abstraction Layer (FAL)](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/Index.html).
2. **Resources** Don't know about /Resources. You typically have `typo3conf/ext/<extension>/Resources`. About your photos: It depends if they are for example part of the theme. Then you would bundle them in an extension (typically a [sitepackage](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/)), or if they are part of the content. Then you would put them in fileadmin.
3. Videos - typically in fileadmin
4. capitalized - it depends: No convention exists for fileadmin, in extensions, the directories are typically capitalized (CamelCase).

An extension is one component that can be installed either by Composer or by using the TYPO3 Extension Manager.

Extensions typically contain the following directory structure:

```
Resources/
├── Private
└── Public
    ├── Css
    ├── Icons
    ├── Images
    └── JavaScript
etc.
```

The file names Css etc. are that way by convention. You can name and configure them differently, but it is good practice to stick to the conventions.

Resources/Public contain the public "assets". These **cannot** be changed and managed in the TYPO3 backend. They are modified by changing them in the extension and then updating the extension on the system.

The directory structure is explained in the official docs:

- [Directory Structure](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html)
- [Extension files](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html)